# wxWidgets - wxUSE_UNICODE_MSLU not defined when building minimal sample using binary in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, wxwidgets

I'm trying to build the minimal wxWidgets sample on Windows, using Visual Studio 2019 Commmunity Edition, following the instructions from [this page](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/plat_msw_binaries.html) for using wxwidget binaries

- I opened the "minimal_vc9.vcxproj" file in Visual Studio. Visual Studio upgrades the project file.
- I then  added the `wxwidgets.props` property file to the property manager, and then tried to build ( `Build | Build Solution` )

It fails with the following error:

```
1>C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wxwidgets\include\wx\msw\chkconf.h(91,1): 
fatal error C1189: #error:  "wxUSE_UNICODE_MSLU must be defined."
```

I am trying to help a friend who knows C++ and uses Windows to set this up, but am not sure how to do so. Note both he and I are new to using Visual Studio as well, and I can't find any references on how to fix this by Googling.

Note I am using the project file that came with minimal (no solution file was there), and can see that in it's configuration that it says "Use Unicode Character Set" at `Project | Properties | Character Set"

EDIT: I'm attaching a picture of the IDE/files we downloaded, which I believe are the 3.1.5 version, ie release version as of Dec 4, 2021?

[image]

Comment: Possibly as simple as defining that symbol in the project settings. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, select "Properties" and navigate to "C/C++" and "Preprocessor". Then add `wxUSE_UNICODE_MSLU` (possibly followed by a `;` separator) in the list of Preprocessor definitions.

Comment: @adrianmole, it shouldn't be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using wxWidgets 3.0, as support for MSLU was removed since v3.1.0 ~8 years ago. Please download 3.1.5 binaries and open `minimal.vcxproj` project file to build the sample, there is really no reason to use a 10 year old version if you're starting developing with wx.

Also, completely unrelated, but it's considered to be a bad idea to use administrator account for development. wxWidgets certainly doesn't require any special rights.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - My friend has left with his PC, so I can't verify, but I did send myself a pic of the issue, and can see that it does appear to the the 3.1.5 binaries we downloaded -  I will check with him again next time I see him!

Comment: Your screenshot shows 3.1.5 archives, but the `setup.h` file opened in your editor is from 3.0. I don't know how did it happen, but you must not have unpacked the archives in the right place. You should remove the existing contents of `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wxwidgets` entirely and unpack 3.1.5 archives there again.

Comment: That must be it? When I have my friend by again, I will do as you suggest.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I
It is very easy to build the library yourself.

Download the source code archive and unpack it in, e.g. c:\wxWidgets

Start msvc, do ^File->Open", navigate to c:\wxWidgets\build\msw and open the file wx_vc15.sln

Select "Build->Batch Build...", click "Select All", then "Build".

When the build is finished successfully, open c:\wxWidgets\samples\minimal\minimal_vc9.sln, let msvc convert it and choose " Build->Build Solution".

Then when everything is ready, create a project as "desktop application", apply the properties file and start coding.

Thank you.